# Date function not working after updrading to mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to query a table and select the rows on the current days. I am using the CURDATE() function but it doesn't seem to be working. Previously on mysql 5.1 it worked perfectly fine. But now it doesn't work.

Below is my query statement. Any help would be really appreciated. When I run this on PHP admin it brings 0 results.

When I remove the "AND DATE(checkout_date - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) = CURDATE( )" it works fine. Thanks

```
SELECT * FROM `checkout` WHERE

  is_confirmed = 0
  AND sent_to_reminder = 1
  AND DATE(checkout_date - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ) = CURDATE( )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a  `)` in the wrong place. Try

```
DATE(checkout_date) - INTERVAL 1 HOUR = CURDATE( )
```

Answer (score 0):

`- INTERVAL 1 HOUR` needs to go outside of your function call:

```
SELECT * FROM `checkout` 
WHERE is_confirmed = 0
AND sent_to_reminder = 1
AND DATE(checkout_date) - INTERVAL 1 HOUR = CURDATE()
```